# How to use object based on async data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I want to init an object based upon NSData came from network.

I am ok to build object based upon async data, but I am wondering how to wait until it is done and go on next command.

May I get some tip or keyword please?

```
ObjWithApi* aObj = [[ObjWithApi alloc]initWithUrl:url];
if(aObj){
    aLabel.text = aObj.title;
}
```

OK，thought lots questioned this question.. but I have my own answer now.
The question is wrong in itself.
What I need was "Do something after data has beed filled", and that means the Block is enough for it.
Sort like

```
[obj getData:^(NSArray* data) {
   make data object by data.
}
```

and reflect to this question, it would be something like

```
@interface someRemoteDataModel 
@implement someRemoteDataModel 
+(void)getData:(NSURL*)url andDoSomething:(void(^)(NSArray* data))block {
    block(data);
}
@end
```

and then

```
[someRemoteDataModel getData:aURL andDoSomething:(^ NSArray *data){
  // fill data object and update UI

}];
```

And if anyone read this, try to convert ur idea to a reasonable way, and find out your own answer.

Comment: what a magic answer..thx tho

Comment: seriously: you are expected to show some real effort on stack overflow if you want to get help. and the minimum request is searching here and google. your question is answered literally a thousand times.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I do believe this is a common question.
But after half hour search, with keywords like init object upon network data, async data with object, or so on..., I just cannot find  matched "questions".. 
Tho my credit is low, that doesn't mean I did no search..
I would be happy if anyone can mark my question is duplicated, if it can help show me the place where to go.

Comment: yes, and as it is common, it does not need to be asked again — the solution is out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or NSURLConnection

**NSURLConnection**

You class must implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and/or `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`;

***Request sending***

```
// Create the POST request to the server.
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];
```

***This data receiving ***

```
#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDataDelegate method/s
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    _myData = [data copy];
    // at this moment you can freely access `_myData` but remember to release it when it is needed
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDelegate method/s
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
{
    // this method will be called if the url connection failed.
}
```

Comment: Hi hccky:
Thanks for your answer and I am sorry I didn't make the question clearly enough.
I know how to async fetch data.
My question is how to know when the class has done the parsing(or fail) and go on next command.

Comment: what about checking `if (_myData != nil) { // do something }`

Comment: That helps..
But what if it takes like 30 secs to fetch data and parse?
Can I wait until it has done?
[code]NewClass* aClass = [[NewClass alloc] initWithUrl:url];
if(aClass==nil){
// it failed, do another thing // after 30 secs
} else {
// do something with this object
}
[code]
Notification might help, but since this is a data object, I would like to wait until it done, otherwise there is no data to display...

Comment: In this case you will probably want to present [UIActivityIndicatorView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) to the user. your optimal way it through async loading, via NSURLConnection or AFNetworking(which is nice framework), when you receive data and there is no error, you start to parse the data, and when parsing is done, and you have data. you remove the activity indicator and fill your view with data.

Comment: Please note that in some scenarios when you have big amount of data to read, it's better to use property in which you will store the temporary data(NSMurableData) and then it's good to use [_myData appendData:data];